# В Visual Studio 2015 пропали все шаблоны приложений

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Вообще не одного шаблона:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал Repair делать, но не помогло.

Пробовал прокликивать по всем фреймворкам, но везде пусто.

Неужели придется VS сносить и с 0 ставить?

То ли после обновления Windows все полетело, то ли после того, как я обновил один из модулей VS...

Если попробовать зайти в обновления и расщирения, то вылетает ошибка :"Не задана ссылка на объект"

Answer (score 1):

Вроде, вот этот ответ помог:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084003/visual-studio-2015-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object

Грохнул все в AppData и все заработало.